# What is the namespace for RouterDB in OsmSharp?

Tags: c#, gps, maps, openstreetmap

I'm trying to run the [CalculateMatrix sample](https://github.com/OsmSharp/samples/blob/master/CalculateMatrix/OsmSharp.CalculateMatrix/Program.cs) from OsmSharp with my own data.

The first step consist in building a router db instance, the OSM wiki says:

```
// using OsmSharp.Routing;
// using OsmSharp.Routing.Osm;
// using OsmSharp.Routing.Osm.Vehicles;

var routerDb = new RouterDb();
using (var stream = new FileInfo(@"/path/to/some/osmfile.osm.pbf").OpenRead())
{
    routerDb.LoadOsmData(stream, Vehicle.Car);
}
```

But it doesnt works because the IDE can not find the namespace for the routerDb object.

Which one is the correct namespace? Or what should I do in order to create a serialized router db file?

Answer (score 0):

According to [RouterDb.cs](https://github.com/OsmSharp/routing/blob/2cd6ea9f49b569627b2b8e2c704741296a0ab384/OsmSharp.Routing/RouterDb.cs) the correct namespace is `OsmSharp.Routing`. Try uncommenting your `using` statements. Note that RouterDb.cs is *not* included in the current master branch of osmsharp.

Answer (score 0):

The `OsmSharp.Routing` project has been renamed `Itinero` and has a new home:

- [GitHub repository](https://github.com/itinero/routing/)
- [Documentation](https://docs.itinero.tech/docs/index.html).